# What steps are involved in porting an Xorg OpenGL app to DirectFB?

Tags: xorg, compiling, make, opengl

I'm looking for a birds-eye view on porting a small app<sup>1</sup> that uses some OpenGL functions from it's home on Xorg to run in a more stand-alone fashion using DirectFB. I am unfamiliar with both C and OpenGL in general.

My motivation is that the embedded platform I want to run this app on (Raspberry Pi) doesn't have accelerated drivers for Xorg yet. I can only get about .5 fps running on Xorg. On the other hand, much heavier weight DirectFB apps seem to run with quite a bit of pep in their step.

What modifications would likely need to be done to the code base and compile process to make a DirectFB port? What sort of dependencies / includes would need to be adapted? Should I be starting from the ground up with a blank slate and implementing each function or working backwards trying to compile/run the original?

1 <sub>I only want to run the display portion of [Lyricue](http://www.lyricue.org/). Sources are [`lyricue_display.c`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chris-debenham/lyricue/main/view/head:/src/lyricue_display.c) and [`lyricue_display.h`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chris-debenham/lyricue/main/view/head:/src/lyricue_display.h)</sub>, but I'd like to see the question answered in a generic way that would be helpful for somebody else wishing to port their favorite app.

Comment: Have you tried XDirectFB?  Keep in mind that openGL code and openGL ES code are not the same, so if the application was written for the former, there may not be any possibility of getting it to run using hardware acceleration on the Pi.

Comment: See also [related question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/4076/233) on [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: This sounds promising but sadly is dead now http://directfb.org/index.php?path=Projects%2FDirectFBGL